# While downgrade component, the @ContentChild(TemplateRef) is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, angular2-components

Using this inside any component:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) public myTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

That will work in angular 2, I could read

```
this.myTemplate
```

But after downgrade the component to work in AngularJS 1.6.2 than

```
this.myTemplate // undefined
```

Is there something I need to do while downgrade? Maybe something to add to my constractor?

Comment: _But after downgrade_.. which version are you using?

Comment: angularJS 1.6.2

Comment: Angular 2.4.8 If that important

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of making it work with downgraded angular components. Refer this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16611